# Log-in problems

Tags: feature-request

I think the log-in system can be improved. I am always logged in on facebook, but I use another facebook account for superuser, stackoverflow, etc.

When I want to log in, it is impossible to log in on the right account! I admit this is a pretty specific situation, but there may be more people experiencing this problem. My solution, for now, is to go to incognito mode, where I'm not logged in to facebook.

Could this perhaps be changed to a system where you choose to login with a different facebook account? Or is this simply impossible because you can only be logged in to facebook with one account at a time?

Comment: You're allowed to have multiple Facebook accounts? I'm asking because of section 4.2 of this document https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms

Comment: Well, as stated there: "You will not create more than one personal account.". I have one account that is not specifically coupled to me as a person. (I have a page for my band that I'm usually logged in to)

Comment: @MonKeePoo what's stopping you from using a Google, Stack Exchange, Yahoo, or other authentication provider? You probably have an account on at least one of the services that you can log in with, and [you can add as many logins to your account as you want](http://superuser.com/users/login). You could even add your 2nd Facebook account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply *any* sso relying on an external site needs you to be logged on to that site - SE then asks the site if the current login is valid, the site checks the credential SE supplies and your current log-in and bob's your uncle, else no. You don't want the Alternate Mon Kee Poo logging in as the real Mon Kee Poo would you (hmm Mon Kee Poo... that sounds just like...) . If you want the technical details - [see wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#Logging_in).

So, no you can't - you will just have to use another openid log in credential (you can have more than one login credential if they're from different places) when you're logged into your other facebook account. That way you can switch between facebook accounts and still log into SE.

I also recall SE does (did?) run its own openid provider , AKA a stack exchange account - you can also do that.

Comment: `Error: too idioms encountered to properly parse answer. Bob may be an uncle.`

Comment: Bob certain isn't an aunt. Maybe a fox?

Answer (score 0):

The single sign on / global auth system expects that you want to either be logged in, or out of, the *network* as a whole.

While we do permit you to have multiple accounts (not just profiles, but actual accounts that don't share credentials) as long as they don't do favors for one another, it's probably not going to get any more convenient to manage them without using incognito mode or a different browser entirely. We have to develop for our use case, and that use case is at a network level.

Another thing you can do is explore the use of browser profiles, because I do understand how frustrating it can be - I have Google accounts for both personal and work use, which gets a tad unruly.

Still, the simplest thing to do is just use incognito / private mode, and keep track of which window you're in.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can't vote you up right now...